# Converting regex %1$d to string in Android

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, spannablestring

I am having `<string name="monthly_savings_other">Monthly savings\n$%1$d</string>` and  i know that because is `%1$d` i can not display it like a string.But i don't know how to formatting properly,although there is a lot examples on internet i just can wrap my head around it.I do not know how to take  `%1$d`
from string folder in android an formatting it.

```
 public void binding(final OtherAccModel modelClass) {
        binding.setOther(modelClass);
        binding.executePendingBindings();


        setSpannableTextWithColor(binding.policyTV, R.string.policy_account_number_other, modelClass.getPolicy(), Color.BLACK);
        setSpannableTextWithColor(binding.companyNameTV,R.string.company_name_other,modelClass.getCompanyName(), Color.BLACK);
        setSpannableTextWithColor(binding.monthlySavingsTV,R.string.monthly_savings_other, String.valueOf(modelClass.getMonthlySavings()), Color.BLACK);
        setSpannableTextWithColor(binding.rorTV,R.string.return_of_value_other, String.valueOf(modelClass.getRor()), Color.BLACK);
        setSpannableTextWithColor(binding.accNameTV,R.string.type_other,modelClass.getType(), Color.BLACK);
        setSpannableTextWithColor(binding.accValueTV,R.string.current_value_other, String.valueOf(modelClass.getCurrentValue()), Color.BLACK);
    }

    void setSpannableTextWithColor(TextView view, int resourceId, String string, int color) {
        if (string == null)
            return;
        String fulltext = context.getResources().getString(resourceId, string);
        String part = string;
        SpannableString str = new SpannableString(fulltext);
        str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), fulltext.length() - part.length(), fulltext.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        view.setText(str);
    }
```

on line `String fulltext = context.getResources().getString(resourceId, string);`  i am getting error

```
java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %1$s instead of %1$d.

d formats a number in decimal digits and can only be used with integers

For further information read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#FormattingAndStyling